# How can i fetch the multiple checked radio button in Servlet page from jsp page as according to my code?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

i am not able to fetch the parameter in servlet page as radio button ->name field is combination of string and number so , m not able to resolve it .

```
list = (ArrayList<QuesnBean>)request.getAttribute("question");
int i=0, l=list.size();
    for(QuesnBean qbean : list)
    {  
     qbean = list.get(i);   
 %>
 <br>
          <div class="card">
             <br>     
               <p class="card-header text-left"> <%=(i+1) %>  : <%=qbean.getQuesn() %>  </p>            
                   <div class="card-body text-left">
                     <input type="radio" name="quizcheck[<%=qbean.getQno() %>]" id="" value="<%=qbean.getOp1()%>"> <%=qbean.getOp1()%><br>
                     <input type="radio" name="quizcheck[<%=qbean.getQno() %>]" id="" value="<%=qbean.getOp2()%>"> <%=qbean.getOp2()%> <br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="quizcheck[<%=qbean.getQno() %>]" id="" value="<%=qbean.getOp3()%>"> <%=qbean.getOp3()%> <br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="quizcheck[<%=qbean.getQno() %>]" id="" value="<%=qbean.getOp4()%>"> <%=qbean.getOp4()%>  <br> 
                      <br>
                     </div>
                    <%  
                        if(i<=l)
                          {
                            i++;
                              }
                        }
                 %>        
                  </div> <br>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit" class="btn btn-success m-auto d-block" />
```

i want to fetch and store the checked radio button value in servlet page for each iteration.Do i have any other technique to solve this, plz let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If value of `<%=qbean.getQno() %>` will be same for all radio button ,you can create a `hidden field` which will have value of this like below i.e :

```
<input type="text" name="radios" value="<%=qbean.getQno() %>">
```

And you can get above `radio button` selected like below :

```
String radio= request.getParameter("radios");

  String r="quizcheck["+radio+"]";
   String r1= request.getParameter(r);//this will give you value of selected radio btn
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thank you . But i m able to fetch one radio button value in servlet , i need all the selected values...!

Comment: For diferent question, you need to used ajax and jquery , and passed the selected value. On button clicked, as this is quiz so everytime question will get change , so you need to used that  . If this helps you please accept this answer :)

Comment: thank you . But actually i will send ( submit )  fixed number question's answer ,suppose 15 answers from the same page , for that what shall i do?

Comment: for that you need to know the name of your radio btn ,or you can have array of radio button and parse through the values ,once submitted.